# How to connect Arduino to brushless motor through only 1 digital pin

Tags: motors, microelectronics, radio

[image: motor]I know how to connect motor to Arduino with 3 wires: 5v, digital pin and ground. As I know only digital wire need to control "speed control" of my motor. So, if my Arduino connected to computer and it is not needed to get this 5v from "speed control". So I decided to remove useless 5v and ground wires. When I remove ground wire, it is okay. But when I remove 5v wire, my motor works about 3-5 seconds on random frequency and then die. So, can I use only 1 digital pin to control my motor?

Comment: Can you give some more detail on the Motor? What is the part number? Can you share picture? In short you will need both 5V and GND for the motor to work. **GND is a very useful signal/wire**

Comment: @mahendra-gunawardena, I add picture, I am not good in this all things, but think that 5v and gnd need only for "servo tester", I have Arduino instead of him, that take energy from my computer. I feed motor from 11.1v li-poly battery

Comment: The speed signal will be defined relative to the ground of the Arduino, which may not have the same potential as the ground of the battery. The motor reads it relative to the battery ground. You need to connect these to common the ground so it all works.

Comment: *why* do you only want to use one pin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have a is a DC brushless motor of type A2212/10T 1400KV. In order for the motor to work you need all three wires. The motor has 3 winding's. Below is good image describing  the motor.

[image]

When you connect two wires example R or L1 at 12V and Y or L2 at 0V only the winding w1 and w2 are energized. So motor will turn a little bit and stop, as you indicated.

Below is an image of the inside of the motor.

[image]

So in order for motor to continue to turn you have energize the another pair of winding's. Take a look at the sequence below.

[image]

I hope I answered your question. Take a look at the references below.

**References**

- [2212 Brushless Motor](https://components101.com/motors/2212-brushless-motor)
- [Brushless DC Motor, How it works ?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bCEiOnuODac)